# EasyMock partial mock private methods

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have the following scenario:

```
public class ClassA {

    public void methodA(){
        try {
            int result=methodB();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           //Some code here
        }
    }

    private int methodB() throws IOException{
        //Some code here
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I want to cover the catch block of the public method methodA() in my test. I don't want to change the visibility of the private method. Is there any way to achieve partial mock of private method using EasyMock? Or is there any way to change the behaviour of private method in my Junit class to throw exception without using mocking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with Easymock alone, you can do this with a combination of EasyMock and Powermock. Then you mock the return value of the private method.

Comment: I was looking if there is any solution available using EasyMock alone.  If not, then i'll use other frameworks.

Comment: Easymock is not capable of mocking private methods. Private methods cannot be mocked. If called, their normal code will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

To test the catch block, you must tell EasyMock to throw an exception when calling methodB.

From the docs:

```
For specifying exceptions (more exactly: Throwables) to be thrown, the object returned 
by expectLastCall() and expect(T value) provides the method andThrow(Throwable throwable).
The method has to be called in record state after the call to the Mock Object for which 
it specifies the Throwable to be thrown.
```

Example:

```
expectLastCall().andThrow(new IOException("Now to test catch block..."));
```

Comment: Nick, the problem is that methodB is a private method. What you suggested works for public methods.